# Python tkinter unable to draw line

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make paint with python tkinter,
But I am unable to draw a line on canvas!
I am on ubuntu 20.04 And here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *


def draw(event):
    startX, startY = event.x, event.y
    my_canvas.create_line(startX, startY, event.x, event.y, fill="black")
    print(startX, startY, event.x, event.y)


root = Tk()
root.title("Colors")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="wheat")
my_canvas.pack()
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- save the `startX` and `startY` on first mouse click
- draw line from `(startX, startY)` to `(event.x, event.y)` on mouse move
- update `startX` and `startY` after drawing the line

```
from tkinter import *

def start_draw(event):
    global startX, startY
    startX, startY = event.x, event.y  # save start position

def draw(event):
    global startX, startY
    my_canvas.create_line(startX, startY, event.x, event.y, fill="black")
    print(startX, startY, event.x, event.y)
    startX, startY = event.x, event.y  # update start position

root = Tk()
root.title("Colors")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="wheat")
my_canvas.pack()

root.bind("<Button-1>", start_draw)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `x0==x1` and `y0==y1` in  `my_canvas.create_line(startX, startY, event.x, event.y, fill="black")` which means both the start point and the endpoint are same. If you want to create straight lines suggest you to create line on buttonpress and save the start points and the line then use `canvas.coords` to update the end points.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

def getStartPoint(event):
    global startX, startY, line
    startX, startY = event.x, event.y

    line = my_canvas.create_line(startX, startY, event.x, event.y, fill="black")

def draw(event):
    my_canvas.coords(line, startX, startY, event.x, event.y)
    print(startX, startY, event.x, event.y)


root = Tk()
root.title("Colors")

startX = None
StartY = None

line = None

my_canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="wheat")
my_canvas.pack()
root.bind('<1>', getStartPoint)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *


def draw(event):
    startX, startY = event.x, event.y
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1 ), (event.y -1 )
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    my_canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 1, fill = "black")
    print(startX, startY, event.x, event.y)

root = Tk()
root.title("Colors")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="white")
my_canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on this site. This answer will be much better if you add an explanation for what you changed or added.